# Can a failed expansion tank cause water heater to stop heating water

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

Yesterday we saw that the expansion tank on our < 8yr old water heater looked like this:
[image]
Hot water is no longer available. If it's possible for the tank spill to cause the heater to stop heating then I'll try to replace the tank. Otherwise, it's wait a week for a plumber to take a look. It's a very busy time for that profession.

Comment: Gas or electric heater?  Is the heater not heating the water or no water coming out?

Comment: It's a gas heater. Heater not heating; water flows.

Comment: Did the leak from the tank go over/onto the heater or just on the floor?  If onto the heater it might have damaged some electrical/control circuit.

Comment: Is the pilot light still lit? You may have to relight it. Have you checked to see if the burner ignites? Review the basics first.

Comment: I would drain the expansion tank first and inspect the pilot fire.

Answer (score 2):

After replacing the tank (easy job after watching a video) I was able to reignite the pilot and the heater is now doing it thermo-increasing job.